# Не вызывается метод RestController в Spring Boot с кастомным фильтром

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Пытаюсь сделать приложение с кастомной аутенфикацией, почему-то не вызывается метод контроллера. Контроллер вызывается с фронта, проходит через мой фильтр, в браузере приходит ответ Ок, но сам контроллер почему-то не вызывается. В чём моя ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const saveUserData = async (userInfo) => {
    return await axiosInstance.post('saveUser', userInfo);
}
```

Контроллер

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthController {
    final UserService userService;

    public AuthController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveUser")
    @ResponseBody
    public VkUser saveUserInfo(@RequestBody VkUser vkUSer) {
        return vkUSer;
    }
}
```

Кастомный фильтр
@Component
public class VkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
private final VkMiniappUserDetailService userDetailService;
final SignChecker signChecker;
private final AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

public VkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter(VkMiniappUserDetailService userDetailService,
                                     SignChecker signChecker,
                                     AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
    this.userDetailService = userDetailService;
    this.signChecker = signChecker;
    this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
}

private final List<String> excludePatches = new ArrayList<>();
private final AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();


@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {


    excludePatches.add("/saveUser");

    if(excludePatches.stream().anyMatch(p -> antPathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath()))) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }


    String sign = request.getHeader("authorization");
    if (sign == null || sign.isEmpty()) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (signChecker.check(request)) {
            String vkId = request.getHeader("vk_user_id");
            if (vkId == null || vkId.isEmpty()) {
                throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Не указан VK ID");
            }
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(vkId);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else throw new BadCredentialsException("Токен не прошёл валидацию");
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        this.authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, e);
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

Конфиг SpringSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
final VkMiniappUserDetailService userDetailService;
final VkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter vkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter;
final VkMiniAppAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

public SpringSecurityConfig(VkMiniappUserDetailService userDetailService, VkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter vkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter, VkMiniAppAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint) {
    this.userDetailService = userDetailService;
    this.vkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter = vkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter;
    this.entryPoint = entryPoint;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);


    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilterBefore(vkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(source), VkMiniAppAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and().sessionManagement().disable();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Я добавила `.antMatchers("/saveUser").permitAll()`, и всё заработало.

Comment: Вы можете отметить свой ответ как правильный, нажав слева на [галочку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour).